# MultiIndexing in pandas based on column conditions

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a huge GPS datasets in a csv file.
It is something like this.

```
12,1999-09-08 12:12:12, 116.3426, 32.5678

12,1999-09-08 12:12:17, 116.34234, 32.5678

.
.
.
```

where each column is in the form of
`id, timestamp, longitude, latitude`

Now, I am using pandas and importing the file into a dataframe, I have so far written this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#this imports the columns and making the timestamp values as row indexes
df = pd.read_csv('/home/abc/Downloads/..../366.txt',delimiter=',',
                index_col=1,names=['id','longitude','latitude'])
#removes repeated entries due to gps errors. 
df = df.groupby(df.index).first()
```

Sometimes, there will be 2 or 3 multiple entries for same date which should be removed

I get something like this

```
                       id  longitude  latitude
1999-09-08 12:12:12    12  116.3426   32.5678
1999-09-08 12:12:17    12  116.34234  32.5678
# and so on with redundant entries removed
```

Now I want rows which have same latitude and longitude to be indexed serially..
i.e., my visualization is

```
                      id  longitude  latitude
0 1999-09-08 12:12:12 12  116.3426    32.5678
1 1999-09-08 12:12:17 12  116.34234   32.5678
2 1999-09-08 12:12:22 12  116.342341  32.5678
  1999-09-08 12:12:27 12  116.342341  32.5678
  1999-09-08 12:12:32 12  116.342341  32.5678
  ....
  1999-09-08 12:19:37 12  116.342341  32.5678
3 1999-09-08 12:19:42 12  116.34234   32.56123
  and so on..
```

i.e., rows with same latitude and longitude values are to be indexed serially. How can i achieve that? i am a beginner in pandas so i don't know much about it. pls help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should leverage the [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and do some math with it:

```
idx = df.duplicated(['longitude', 'latitude'])
idx *= -1
idx += 1
idx.ix[0] = 0
df = df.set_index(idx.cumsum(), append=True).swaplevel(0,1)
```

---

**How the code works**

Starting with the `df` you get:

```
In [215]: df
Out[215]: 
                     id   longitude  latitude
stamp                                        
1999-09-08T12:12:12  12  116.342600  32.56780
1999-09-08T12:12:17  12  116.342340  32.56780
1999-09-08T12:12:22  12  116.342341  32.56780
1999-09-08T12:12:27  12  116.342341  32.56780
1999-09-08T12:12:32  12  116.342341  32.56780
1999-09-08T12:19:37  12  116.342341  32.56780
1999-09-08T12:19:42  12  116.342340  32.56123
```

First calculate the consecutive duplicated `(longitude, latitude)` tuples:

```
In [216]: idx = df.duplicated(['longitude', 'latitude'])

In [217]: idx
Out[217]: 
stamp
1999-09-08T12:12:12    False
1999-09-08T12:12:17    False
1999-09-08T12:12:22    False
1999-09-08T12:12:27     True
1999-09-08T12:12:32     True
1999-09-08T12:19:37     True
1999-09-08T12:19:42    False
```

Then we use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to create a zero-based index that does not increment on duplicaes.
Put some math with it to obtain zeros on duplicated rows and ones for others:

```
In [218]: idx *= -1
In [219]: idx += 1


In [220]: idx
Out[220]: 
stamp
1999-09-08T12:12:12    1
1999-09-08T12:12:17    1
1999-09-08T12:12:22    1
1999-09-08T12:12:27    0
1999-09-08T12:12:32    0
1999-09-08T12:19:37    0
1999-09-08T12:19:42    1
```

As we want a zero-based index, we set the first cell to `0`, and we append that column to the index of `df` to create the `MultiIndex`:

```
In [221]: idx.ix[0] = 0
In [222]: df = df.set_index(idx.cumsum(), append=True)
```

By default, `set_index` adds the index at an inferior level than the existing one. We must finish by swapping the levels between the timestamps and our additional index:

```
In [223]: df = df.swaplevel(0,1)

In [224]: df
Out[224]: 
                       id   longitude  latitude
  stamp                                        
0 1999-09-08T12:12:12  12  116.342600  32.56780
1 1999-09-08T12:12:17  12  116.342340  32.56780
2 1999-09-08T12:12:22  12  116.342341  32.56780
  1999-09-08T12:12:27  12  116.342341  32.56780
  1999-09-08T12:12:32  12  116.342341  32.56780
  1999-09-08T12:19:37  12  116.342341  32.56780
3 1999-09-08T12:19:42  12  116.342340  32.56123
```